# Can I recover dropped database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, recover

I accidentally dropped a database which I used for my web application, and it is in MySQL. Browsing through the internet I found out that to recover you need to have binary logs enabled. Read that binary logs records only changes in tables, so what it has to do with recovering a db. Upon executing the command "show binary logs;" console shows me "Error Code: 1381. You are not using binary logging". I am a newbie to MySQL, so is it possible to recover it without my binary logging enabled PLUS I have not made any real backup for the db. Going through the MySQL "my.cnf" file found that InnoDB is default enabled, can it help me recover.

If I cannot recover, please mention the steps to be carried out next time creating a new db to ensure that I could recover even if it has been accidentally deleted.

Comment: Hope this link will help you.. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-dropped-mysql-database

Comment: binary logs are not enabled on your server so there is no chance even it it was enabled then also seems impossible as practically your server don't keep binary logs since database was created....so better option is that restore from last backup if you are taking...other wise god bless you...

Answer (score 1):

I think it can't be recovered. In case of this case, you can do the following when creating a new db:

1. open the binary log by add the following:

   log-bin=/data/mysqlbinlog/mysql-bin
   binlog-format=mixed (or row)
2. create a slave db.

Good luck for you.